# How to arrange multiple JPanels?

Tags: java, swing, matrix

I am in the beginning process of coding a matrix project for my coding class. I am currently just trying to get the GUI looking the way I want it. Here is a quick sketch of how I want it to look:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hmt-9DNH6CGtV1eBJYSOu72Iu2cAqPe8/view?usp=sharing

(The pic is too big to upload so linking the Drive was the next best option.)

Basically, The user would enter in the rows and columns of their 2 matrices, and press the button to calculate. The program would ensure the 2 matrices were compatible, prompt for specific numbers, and then the final calculations would appear in the labels.

The issue is I'm still pretty inexperienced in Java, and this is my first time working with more than 1 JPanel. Here is the code I've written for my Gui so far:

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class GuiWindow {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JFrame myGUI = new JFrame();
    myGUI.setTitle("Matrix Project");
    myGUI.setSize(600,600);
    myGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1); //borders

    JLabel AddLabel = new JLabel(); //creates JLabels
    AddLabel.setBorder(border);

    JLabel SubLabel = new JLabel();
    SubLabel.setBorder(border);

    JLabel MultLabel = new JLabel();
    MultLabel.setBorder(border);

    JPanel main = new JPanel(); //Adds JLabel panel
    myGUI.add(main);
    main.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
    main.setAlignmentY(Component.TOP_ALIGNMENT);
    main.add(MultLabel);
    main.add(SubLabel);
    main.add(AddLabel);

    JTextField row1txt = new JTextField(); //textfields to input rows and columns
    row1txt.setText("Matrix 1 rows...");
    JTextField column1txt = new JTextField();
    column1txt.setText("Matrix 1 columns...");
    JTextField row2txt = new JTextField();
    row2txt.setText("Matrix 2 rows...");
    JTextField column2txt = new JTextField();
    column2txt.setText("Matrix 2 columns...");

    JPanel input = new JPanel(); //adds textfield panel
    myGUI.add(input);
    input.setLayout(new GridLayout (2, 2, 3, 3));
    input.add(row1txt);
    input.add(column1txt);
    input.add(row2txt);
    input.add(column2txt);


    JButton Calc = new JButton(); //button to eventually calculate
    Calc.setText("Calculate");

    JPanel CalcButton = new JPanel(); //adds button panel
    myGUI.add(CalcButton);
    CalcButton.add(Calc); 

    myGUI.setVisible(true); //instantiates the gui
}

}
```

When I load the code, All I see is the button. This makes sense. I have nothing splitting up the 3 JPanels into different sections, so Java is just sort of laying them on top of each other. So here, of course, is the question: How would you split these Jpanels up into separate sections of the JFrame so it could look at least sort of like my sketch?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The first thing you want to do is take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) - any answer which doesn't suggest using one or more appropriate layouts is misleading you

Comment: Based on your image, I see the possible use of a `GridLayout`, a `GridBagLayout` and probably a `BorderLayout`

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you want to do is have a read through [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).

You could probably do this using compounding `GridLayout`s, but to my money, `GridBagLayout` offers more flexibility.

[image: Layout]

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 0.5;
            add(new TopPane(), gbc);

            gbc.weightx = 0.5;
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            gbc.gridwidth = 1;
            add(new CheckerPane(), gbc);

            gbc.gridx++;
            add(new JButton("Button"), gbc);
        }

    }

    public class TopPane extends JPanel {

        public TopPane() {
            setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 3));
            add(new JLabel("label1", JLabel.CENTER));
            add(new JLabel("label2", JLabel.CENTER));
            add(new JLabel("label3", JLabel.CENTER));
        }

    }


    public class CheckerPane extends JPanel {

        public CheckerPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            add(new JCheckBox("Tick box 1"), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(new JCheckBox("Tick box 2"), gbc);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JCheckBox("Tick box 3"), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(new JCheckBox("Tick box 4"), gbc);
        }

    }

}
```